# Pushkit with Sinch VOIP not working with pushkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, sinch, pushkit

I am trying to implement App-to-App calling with Sinch in my IOS app. I have implemented Pushkit in my iOS app with Sinch but the push notification is not working when the app is in background.

**I have two questions.**

1. Do I need another web service to send push notification to my app for incoming app separately or Sinch handles it itself.
2. If it does handle itself then what am I missing in my code.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

    [self handleLocalNotification:[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]];

    self.push = [Sinch managedPushWithAPSEnvironment:SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic];
    self.push.delegate = self;
    [self.push setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically];

    [self.push registerUserNotificationSettings];

    return YES;
 }
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary *)options {
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                           sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                  annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  }

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                  annotation:annotation];
}

- (id<SINClient>)client {
   return _sinchClient;
}
-(void)clientDidFail:(id<SINClient>)client error:(NSError *)error{

   NSLog(@"fail");
}

-(void)clientDidStart:(id<SINClient>)client{

    NSLog(@"Start");
    [self voipRegistration];
}


- (void)client:(id<SINClient>)client
   logMessage:(NSString *)message
      area:(NSString *)area
    severity:(SINLogSeverity)severity
   timestamp:(NSDate *)timestamp {
// If you want all messages remove the if statement

    if (severity == SINLogSeverityCritical) {
        NSLog(@"%@", message);
    }
}

- (void)initSinchClientWithUserId:(NSString *)userId {
    if (!_sinchClient) {

        _sinchClient = [Sinch clientWithApplicationKey:@"<my-key>"
                                applicationSecret:@"<my-secret>"
                                  environmentHost:@"sandbox.sinch.com"
                                           userId:userId];

        _sinchClient.delegate = self;

        [_sinchClient setSupportCalling:YES];
        [_sinchClient startListeningOnActiveConnection];
        [_sinchClient enableManagedPushNotifications];
        [_sinchClient start];
    }
 }
 - (void)handleLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if (notification) {
        id<SINNotificationResult> result = [self.sinchClient      relayLocalNotification:notification];
        if ([result isCall] && [[result callResult] isTimedOut]) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Missed call"
                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Missed call from %@", [[result callResult] remoteUserId]]
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}

-(void)voipRegistration
{
    PKPushRegistry* voipRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    voipRegistry.delegate = self;
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];
}

-(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type
{
    [_sinchClient registerPushNotificationData:credentials.token];
}
-(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry   didInvalidatePushTokenForType:(PKPushType)type{

     NSLog(@"invalidated");
}
-(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry   didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:  (NSString *)type
{
    //notify
    NSDictionary* dic = payload.dictionaryPayload;
    NSString* sinchinfo = [dic objectForKey:@"sin"];
    UILocalNotification* notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notif.alertBody = @"incoming call";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notif];
    if (sinchinfo == nil)
        return;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_sinchClient relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:sinchinfo];
    });
}
```

Comment: HAve you uploaded the Voip Certificate to Sinch in the dashboard?

Comment: yes, I did. @cjensen

Comment: Check, might be your app is crashing in terminated or background mode.

Comment: No Sir, It is not crashing.

Comment: @WaleedVic, I am also getting same issue. Sinch push notification is not working when app is in background. Did you find solution ? Thanks

Comment: @gstream79 , no Sir  , I didnt, I emailed the guys and they said the'd been working on it, will be out soon, dont know how soon.

Comment: @WaleedVic, I've solved this issue.

Comment: @gstream79 ur a god damn genius. May I ask for the solution?

Comment: @WaleedVicm, just added answer as solution

Comment: @gstream79 facing background issues in a sinch can you help

Comment: @Achilles help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you integrated Pushkit and Sinch then push notification may can't catch on PushKit's delegate function - didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload. But you can get push notification on SINManagedPushDelegate's function - didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload.
Push notification is not coming but you can get incoming call event on there when app is in background. You can trigger local notification if app is in background to let user incoming call know.

Hope that would be helpful for you.

Comment: because didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload the Questionest person have mention this delegate in his problem and he is not receiving the push still

Comment: Still the push is not receiwing when the app quit i hawe a little job for you fir help me in this issue, commint me and let me leawe the skype id here

Comment: SinManagedPush + CallKit works perfectly in iOS 13.

Comment: is your issue fixed, can someone help me I will really appreciate

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper, what's your issue?

Comment: @gstream79 Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push callback

Comment: Hey @MeetIosDeveloper, you need to report incoming call to system using CallKit. It is mandatory from ios13. Otherwise, voip call will not work.

Comment: I have used all possible solutions can help in my code

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper, can you post your AppDelegate and Sinch related code ?

Comment: @gstream79 sir I have posted a question regarding this I will post there

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper, can you post your ask link here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540239/ios-13-callkit-crash-when-app-in-background-using-sinch/62541136?noredirect=1#comment110642614_62541136

Comment: @gstream79 please help bro