# VOIP Sinch in iOS 11 not work in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, sinch, pushkit

I use Sinch VOIP to make calling between App-To-App in iOS 11.1.2
Work well when the application status is foreground but in background and terminated nothing happened after I open the application console print

```
Pubnub request SCHEDULED (ID=081E49C2-C30A-4B4B-840C-E6A6051E6F44, URL=https://rebtelsdk.pubnub.com/subscribe/sub-c-c5e52f20-d446-11e3-b488-02ee2ddab7fe/5e1e1309-136a-40d4-935f-2627ebe4e8f2B/0/0, NST-VoIP: NO)


Pubnub request STARTED (ID=081E49C2-C30A-4B4B-840C-E6A6051E6F44)
Pubnub request SUCCESS (ID=081E49C2-C30A-4B4B-840C-E6A6051E6F44):
(
        (
    ),
    15117251992031337
)

onPubSubSubscriptionSuccess: userInfo: {
    channel = "5e1e1309-136a-40d4-935f-2627ebe4e8f2B";
    subscribeSequence = 1;
    timetoken = 0;
    useVoIPNetworkServiceType = 0;
}
```

I upload VOIP & APNS certificates to Sinch dashboard and I used `SINManagedPush` & `PushKit` My code is

> 1. Setup Push Manager & SINClient in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    self.push = [Sinch managedPushWithAPSEnvironment:SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic];
    self.push.delegate = self;
    [self.push setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically];
    void (^onUserDidLogin)(NSString *) = ^(NSString *userId) {
    [self.push registerUserNotificationSettings];
    [self initSinchClientWithUserId:userId];
    };
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserverForName:@"UserDidLoginNotification"
    object:nil
    queue:nil
    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
     NSString *userId = note.userInfo[@"userId"];

     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userId     forKey:@"userId"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
     onUserDidLogin(userId);
     }];


     - (void)initSinchClientWithUserId:(NSString *)userId {
    if (!_client) {
    _client = [Sinch clientWithApplicationKey:@"APP-Key"
                            applicationSecret:@"APP-Secret"
                              environmentHost:@"sandbox.sinch.com"
                                       userId:userId];

    _client.delegate = self;
    _client.callClient.delegate = self;
    [_client setSupportCalling:YES];
    [_client enableManagedPushNotifications];

    [_client start];
    [_client startListeningOnActiveConnection];
    _callKitProvider = [[SINCallKitProvider alloc] initWithClient:_client];


    }
    }
```

> 2. Get Device Token

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{


[self.push application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);

[self.push application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification.request.content.userInfo];
}


-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
completionHandler();
[self.push application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] didReceiveRemoteNotification:response.notification.request.content.userInfo];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
[self.push application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}
```

> 3. PushKit

```
-(void)voipRegistration
{
PKPushRegistry* voipRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
voipRegistry.delegate = self;
voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];
}

 -(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type
{

[_client registerPushNotificationData:credentials.token];
 }
 -(void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry   didInvalidatePushTokenForType:(PKPushType)type{


NSLog(@"invalidated");

 }
```

> 4.Call voipRegistration when SINClient start

```
- (void)clientDidStart:(id<SINClient>)client {
NSLog(@"Sinch client started successfully (version: %@)", [Sinch version]);
[self voipRegistration];
}
```

> 5.Implement SINManagedPushDelegate & SINCallClientDelegate

```
- (void)client:(id<SINCallClient>)client didReceiveIncomingCall:(id<SINCall>)call {

UIViewController *top = self.window.rootViewController;
while (top.presentedViewController) {
    top = top.presentedViewController;
}
[top performSegueWithIdentifier:@"callView" sender:call];
}

- (SINLocalNotification *)client:(id<SINClient>)client localNotificationForIncomingCall:(id<SINCall>)call {
SINLocalNotification *notification = [[SINLocalNotification alloc] init];
NSArray * ansAr = @[@"رد",@"Answer"];
NSArray * MsgAr = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"مكالمة لم يرد عليها من %@", [call remoteUserId]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Incoming call from %@", [call remoteUserId]]];
notification.alertAction = ansAr[self.languageID];
notification.alertBody = MsgAr[self.languageID];
return notification;
}
- (void)client:(id<SINClient>)client willReceiveIncomingCall:(id<SINCall>)call {

[self.callKitProvider reportNewIncomingCall:call];
}
```

These is the code , Please help me if I forgot anything.
I checked the `credentials.token` is not null.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup the Sinch managed push with the code below:

```
self.push = [Sinch managedPushWithAPSEnvironment:SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic];
self.push.delegate = self;
[self.push setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically];
```

The Sinch SDK will automatically do all the PushKit registration for you. So step 3 and 4 in your description is not necessary and should not be there. Part of the code in step 2 is not needed as well. Please take a look at the Sinch CallKit sample app from the SDK download package, and refer to the implementation of that App.

Below is a demo video made with the 3.12.4 Sinch SDK CallKit Sample App without any tweak, the device used in the demo is an iPhone7 running iOS 11, it gets the incoming call in background, killed and lockscreen mode:

[Sinch CallKit Sample App Demo Video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AgfbTtGQOGvz4keHeB8GAb7hWysb)

Also, note that callKit only works with VoIP push, have you uploaded the right type of push certificate to Sinch Portal?[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you force kill an app apple wont wake the app for VoIP push, if you just have in background or reboot the phone apple will wake it up. Annoying, but that's apple

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Please how can I wake app or receive the calling in background mode ? , I am using pushKit and I want only to receive calling when I press home button and the status of app is background

Comment: @Hazoomo, please see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609204/pushkit-with-sinch-voip-not-working-with-pushkit/46520688#46520688

Comment: @cjensen latest Sample iOS SDK not work in background sinchCallingPush , sinchCallKit