# iOS 13 callkit crash when app in background using sinch

Tags: ios, swift, sinch, callkit, pushkit

Using call kit, push kit and Sinch for the audio-video call. The call is working fine when app is active but crashes when the app in the background

**Assertion failure in -[PKPushRegistry _terminateAppIfThereAreUnhandledVoIPPushes], /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/PushKit/PushKit-37/PKPushRegistry**

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Killing app because it never posted an incoming call to the system after receiving a PushKit VoIP push callback.' ***

The issue is on StackOverflow but unable to fix solution

Answer (score 0):

have you used our CallKit sample voice App?

Are you able to reproduce the same error when using our sample apps?

We'll need your Sinch account info and a callID of the failed calls using our sample apps to track your issue.

Thank you  Sinch Voice & Video Team

Comment: yes I used your sample app with my keys its working fine but the problem is it is in 0bjectice c call appears only one time where can I further contact with you

Comment: You must contact us via support@sinch.com. Describe your issue, what SDK version you are using and at least one Call_ID for the failed calls.